# Grouping age range in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have got a Client table with ClientID (PK) and DOB field with Date/Time as data type. I need to create a query to workout the age groups, for eg:

```
Age Group  Count

18 – 24      2
25 - 35      1
36 - 45      2
46 - 55      5
56 - 65      0
66+          2
Not stated   5
Total        17
```

I have got the following sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Partition(DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Date())(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([DOB]),Day([DOB]))>Date()),19,66,8) AS Range, 
Count(ClientsDetails.ClientID) AS CountOfAgeGroups
FROM ClientsDetails
GROUP BY Partition(DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Date())+(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([DOB]),Day([DOB]))>Date()),19,66,8);
```

And it produces the following result:

```
Range    CountOfAgeGroup   
:18      1
27:34    4
35:42    1
67:      1
```

Could someone please guide me on what changes I should make to the query or possibly advice the best solution to achieve the desired result, as I am not too familiar with Access.

Thanks in advance.

This is the second part of my query. Is it also possible to find the age group between two dates using parameter search. For example if I want to find the age group between 01/01/14 and 17/03/14. I have tried the following using the solution posted by Gord Thompson, but it is throwing incorrect expression error:

```
SELECT [%$##@_Alias].AgeGroup, Count(*) AS CountOfAgeGroup, Support.ClientID
FROM (SELECT Switch([Age] Between 18 And 24, "18-24", [Age] Between 25 And 35, "25-35", [Age] Between 36 And 45, "36-45", [Age] Between 46 And 55, "46-55",[Age] Between 56 And 65,  "56-65",[Age] > 66, "66+") AS AgeGroup FROM (SELECT DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Date())-IIf(Format(Date(),"mmdd")<Format([DOB],"mmdd"),1,0) AS Age FROM ClientsDetails)  AS [%$##@_Alias])  AS [%$##@_Alias], Support
GROUP BY [%$##@_Alias].AgeGroup,Support.ClientID
HAVING (((Support.ClientID) Between [Enter Start Date] And [Enter End Date]));
```

Comment: This is now resolved by using the following:
SELECT AgeGroup,
Count(*) As CountOfAgeGroup
FROM
(
SELECT
SWITCH ([Age] Between 18 And 24, "18-24", [Age] Between 25 And 35, "25-35", [Age] Between 36 And 45, "36-45", [Age] Between 46 And 55, "46-55",[Age] Between 56 And 

65, "56-65",[Age] > 66, "66+") AS AgeGroup
FROM
(
SELECT 
    DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Date())-IIf(Format(Date(),"mmdd")<Format([DOB],"mmdd"),1,0) AS Age
FROM ClientsDetails, Support
WHERE ClientsDetails.ClientID = Support.ClientID
AND ReferralReceivedDate BETWEEN [Enter Start Date] AND [Enter End Date]
)
)
GROUP BY AgeGroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we start with a query that calculates the actual age in years (based on a [Date_of_Birth] field and the `Date()`function)

```sql
SELECT 
    DateDiff("yyyy",[Date_of_Birth],Date())-IIf(Format(Date(),"mmdd")<Format([Date_of_Birth],"mmdd"),1,0) AS Age
FROM Students
```

then we can use that as a subquery and apply the `Switch()` function (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx)) to assign an [AgeGroup] to each entry

```sql
SELECT
    Switch([Age] Between 0 And 17, "0-17", [Age] Between 18 And 24, "18-24", [Age] Between 25 And 35, "25-35", [Age] > 35, "Over 35") AS AgeGroup
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DateDiff("yyyy",[Date_of_Birth],Date())-IIf(Format(Date(),"mmdd")<Format([Date_of_Birth],"mmdd"),1,0) AS Age
        FROM Students
    )
```

and then wrap the whole thing in an aggregation query

```sql
SELECT
    AgeGroup,
    Count(*) AS CountOfAgeGroup
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Switch([Age] Between 0 And 17, "0-17", [Age] Between 18 And 24, "18-24", [Age] Between 25 And 35, "25-35", [Age] > 35, "Over 35") AS AgeGroup
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    DateDiff("yyyy",[Date_of_Birth],Date())-IIf(Format(Date(),"mmdd")<Format([Date_of_Birth],"mmdd"),1,0) AS Age
                FROM Students
            )
    )
GROUP BY AgeGroup
```

to get results like this

```
AgeGroup  CountOfAgeGroup
--------  ---------------
0-17                    5
18-24               12897
25-35                3537
Over 35               766
```